# How to check if GoogleApiClient is connected?

Tags: android, google-api-client

I have a app with maps, and If this app is opened for the first time without internet connection, the Map doesn't show but the location keeps updating. How to check if is connected so then show the map to the user. Using `if(mGoogleApiClient != null){` is not working, it always pass even without internet connection, as I mentioned, without internet it keeps updating the location, but not showing the map!

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the [`GoogleApiClient.isConnected()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#isConnected()) method to check if its connected or not. It has so far worked for me great.

> ```
>  public boolean isConnected ()
> ```
>
> Checks if the client is currently connected to the service, so that
>   requests to other methods will succeed. Applications should guard
>   client actions caused by the user with a call to this method.

You can make your `Activity` implement a `GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks`to know when its connected. It has an `onConnected()` method where you can write code when connected.

```
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d("Connected", "Connected");
        // Do the Map related work.
    }
```

To know about the `Bundle` parameter, refer to the docs [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks).

Answer (score 0):

`mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()` will return true if your `GoogleApiClient` iscooncted

[public abstract boolean isConnected ()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient#isConnected())
Checks if the client is currently connected to the service, so that requests to other methods will succeed. Applications should guard client actions caused by the user with a call to this method.

Answer (score 0):

If you just check `mGoogleApiClient` , it will always return true because you have assigned it and is not null. You are not checking the connection. Instead, try `mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()` and it will return true after a successful connection.

Answer (score 0):

> public abstract boolean isConnected ()

Checks if the client is currently connected to the service, so that requests to other methods will succeed. Applications should guard client actions caused by the user with a call to this method.

Returns
`true` if the client is connected to the service.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient#isConnected()